# derby db authorization not working

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I created a database by using this code:

```
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:./db;create=true;user=qwe;password=qwe");
    conn.close();
```

After that I see ./db folder.

The database is not protected by any authorization.
I can connect to the db by using netbeans or idea without entering a user id and a password.

How can I protect the db with an authorization system?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/security/

In particular, study user authentication (which is **different** than authorization): http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/security/cseccsecure42374.html